# Using hibernate return count value of a query

Tags: hibernate

this is my mysql query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM bw_jobs 
WHERE year(job_date)=year(curdate()) AND month(job_date)=month(curdate());
```

How to use this in hibernate to get count value?

Comment: hi i got it . Tha answer is SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = factory.openSession();
            SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT count(*) as noofjobs FROM bw_jobs where  year(job_date)=year(curdate()) and month(job_date)=month(curdate());");
            sqlQuery.addScalar("noofjobs",Hibernate.INTEGER);
            Integer i=(Integer)sqlQuery.uniqueResult();

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
String hql = "select count(job.id) from Job job"
             + " where year(job.jobDate) = year(current_date())"
             + " and month(job.jobDate) = month(current_date())";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
return ((Number) query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

(assuming the bw_jobs table is mapped by the Job entity, and the job_date column is mapped to the jobDate property)

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions for the list of functions supported by Hibernate.